# toast cannot be resolved and activitynotfoundexception cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, google-maps, exception, toast

I want to import google maps in my app.

This is the code:
     public static void maps(Activity activity, String address) {

```
try {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + address));
    activity.startActivity(intent);

} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(activity, activity.getString(R.id.webView), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}

public static void navigation(Activity activity, String address) {

try {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" +       address));
    activity.startActivity(intent);

} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

    Toast.makeText(activity, activity.getString(R.id.webView), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Il get 2 errors. ActivityNotFoundException cannot be resolved to a type and Toast cannot be resolved.

How this is possible?

Thanx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because of missing import statements..Import those packege by pressing `ctrl+shift+o` in your eclipse..
or add those package in header section..